# Looking for a DynamoDB/MongoDB+Redis mixture?

Tags: mongodb, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store some data with something similar structure:

```
"groups": {
    "g01": {
        "person_id_01": {
            "active": true
            ...
        },
        "person_id_02": {
            "active": true
            ...
        },
        "person_id_03": {
            "active": false
            ...
        }
    },
    "g02": {
        "person_id_04": {
            "active": true
            ...
        },
        "person_id_05": {
            "active": false
            ...
        },
        "person_id_06": {
            "active": false
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

So I have groups, and people in each group with some parameters.
I need to monitor each of these groups nearly real-time, like how many active people I have in each group. So for this I would have to query the DB every second. If I launch multiple apps to scale my application they would monitor different groups, so the read/s would be more and more. If I monitor 10 groups it could be 10 read/s from different applications.

So for this probably DynamoDB is not ideal and I am thinking on Redis, but in Redis it seems problematic to store and search in a complex data structure like this.

What would be your recommendation to store this and have access to near real-time data (like number of active people in a group) for multiple applications?
I could use different databases too if these won't suite this use case.

Thanks,
z

Answer (score 0):

I would use DynamoDB and probably the [adjacency list pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html). For the number of people in a group, if that is a value you need to get often, I'd have an out of band lambda function that pre-computes that for me to satisfy your "near real time" requirement. I would also go to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k) a few times.

BTW, 10 reads/sec is nothing. If you model the schema correctly, DynamoDB can do 10 million a second.